# Hibernate OneToMany Relation unable to get child

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am new in hibernate and trying to learn basics. I am trying to implement oneToMany mapping but I have problem when I make a get request. Basically response does not show child entity.

```
 public class Student implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private int id;

        private String name;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        Set<Course> courseList;
    }

 public class Course {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private int id;

        private String name;

}
```

I know this is not optimal way but I am just trying to see how hibernates creates sql. I use spring jpa repositories to get all student classes. As I check database course and student relation is correct. But courseList is empty in student GET request. I do not understand why.

Here is the output of hibernate:

```
 select
        student0_.id as id1_1_,
        student0_.name as name2_1_ 
    from
        students student0_


select
        courselist0_.student_id as student_1_2_0_,
        courselist0_.course_list_id as course_l2_2_0_,
        course1_.id as id1_0_1_,
        course1_.name as name2_0_1_,
        course1_.student_id as student_3_0_1_,
        student2_.id as id1_1_2_,
        student2_.name as name2_1_2_ 
    from
        students_course_list courselist0_ 
    inner join
        courses course1_ 
            on courselist0_.course_list_id=course1_.id 
    left outer join
        students student2_ 
            on course1_.student_id=student2_.id 
    where
        courselist0_.student_id=?
```

Note : In debug I can see that child entity was populated. But response does not include it.

Note 2: Additionally I wonder why hibernate creates same sql (second one which fetches the child entity) when I use fetchType.LAZY

Comment: Try to execute a simple query with entityManager for test purposes. ```em.find(Student.class, studentId)``` and see what query will be generated

Comment: Are your entities complete with that code? If yes this can't be working. If no, please provide the full code. If you want this to work you must define the complete relationship. You need a mapping between the two entities which is obviously missing.

Comment: there are only constructor, setters and getters nothing more. Why mapping is missing ? In debug mode I can see object is populated correctly with child entities. Anc I can access them. Only JSON response does not include it.